# Unexpected behavior when printf is used after fork() and the parent is on wait()

Tags: c, fork, wait

I have the following 2 sets of code that output differently. [outputting to the terminal]

Code 1:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main ()
{ 
    printf("before the fork\n");
    fflush(stdout);
    int pid=fork();
    printf("after the fork\n");

    if (pid == 0)  
    {
        sleep(1);
        printf("I'm child");
    }
    else   
    {
        wait();
        printf ("I'm parent");
    }
    exit(0);
}
```

Output 1:

```
before the fork
after the fork
after the fork
I'm child
```

Now only the printf after the fork is commented and we see the printf after wait() for the parent process works as expected.

Code 2:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main ()
{ 
    printf("before the fork\n");
    fflush(stdout);
    int pid=fork();
    // printf("after the fork\n");

    if (pid == 0)  
    {
        sleep(1);
        printf("I'm child");
    }
    else   
    {
        wait();
        printf ("I'm parent");
    }
    exit(0);
}
```

Output 2:

```
before the fork
I'm childI'm parent
```

I am confused as in how the printf after the fork() messes up the output.

Note the following output too

Code 3:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main ()
{ 
    printf("before the fork\n");
    fflush(stdout);
    int pid=fork();
    printf("after the fork\n");

    if (pid == 0)  
    {
        sleep(1);
        printf("I'm child");
    }
    else   
    {
        //wait();
        printf ("I'm parent");
    }
    exit(0);
}
```

Output 3:

```
before the fork
after the fork
I'm parentafter the fork
I'm child
```

Any idea why this discrepancy?

Comment: Have you tried adding `\n` to the other `printf` or `fflush(stdout)` after the other prints? The stdout of the parent may not be flushed.

Comment: Is your output to a tty or to a regular file?

Comment: What is `wait()`?  Typically, `wait` takes an argument.

Comment: @WilliamPursell the output is to the terminal

Comment: @dlivshen have tried both of that. doesn't impact the result except some line breaks

Comment: As @william-pursell wrote, `wait` typically gets an output parameter for the status. What `wait` are you using?

Comment: [Enable warnings and treat them as errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57842756/why-should-i-always-enable-compiler-warnings).

Comment: If you've included the required header, which is `<sys/wait.h>`, your code will not compile. Since you don't have a `wait` function declaration in scope, gcc automatically generates one (an incorrect one) for you.

Comment: I don't know why your code doesn't work though. Despite of calling `wait` incorrectly, your code should still work, and it does work on my machiine.

Comment: Actually it should not compile at all. And if it compiles because you disabled some warnings, you will still fail on linking stage. Anyway after the processes are closed, stdout is flushed so you should see everything on the stream, the order is not guaranteed though. The only scenario I can think about it does not happen is if parent silently crashes. Maybe check for coredumps?

Comment: @YuriNudelman C functions don't have name mangling, so argument types don't matter. Linking will succeed as long as the function name matches.

Comment: @yyy thinking of it, you are right. And this may actually explain the behavior. Suppose, somehow, he managed to compile with wait without passing it an argument. As a result, the function will use whatever it has on stack, which may be garbage. In that case it is likely that the parent gets a segmentation fault, and crashes silently. This explains why there is no parent print.

Comment: @YuriNudelman I thought that's the reason, too. But after I tried that, I found that `wait` does not crash, instead it returns -1 with `errno` set to `EFAULT` when `int *wstatus` it non-writeable. I'm not sure if it depends on the version of glibc.

Answer (score 0):

It's not because of the  `printf("after the fork\n");` that you get different output.

The reason is when fork() system call is invoked you create a `child process`. And the both the `parent process` and `child process` both are running concurrently. So we don't know which would get priority (maybe parent or child).

[My output in a online compiler.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ugkyH.png)

In code2, the child process got the preference and so it executes first, followed by parent process.

Also in code 3, wait() system call is invoked, so if parent process gets the preference , it gets executed till the `wait()`. After that the child process is executed and after termination of child process, the parent process continues from where it left.

[refer this for more understanding](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/wait-system-call-c/)

Comment: OP's asking why "I'm parent" doesn't present in output1

Comment: @yyyy I think its because of compiler, I am getting the `printf("after the fork\n");` in online compiler and my linux machine.